# android httpclient Handling many requests to the server

Tags: php, android, httpclient

I have a android app that works like a chat where the users send and receive messages , the app has a Service that makes sql requests to the php server each 60 seconds ,because it has to verify if has a new message if has then the user is notified, my question is there is a better way to do this to don't overload the server

Comment: You could have the server push state to the application, instead of the other way around.

Comment: ajax push or parse.com push may help u out